# How to add short code (embed) into additional css of wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, embed, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

My question is simple. I have a shortcode: e.g.

`[ivory-search id="111" title="Search"]`

I want to add it to specific part of website using additional css: e.g.

`.header.menue`

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about my answer but maybe you can try with javascript. When DOM the DOM is fully loaded, get Elements by ID or ClassNames and append it ? But not sure the shortcode will works...